# Microsoft Driver for SQL Server 2016 - Installation

Tags: php, sql-server-2016

My question is based off of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409754/php-with-sql-server)'s answer from @Crontab. I downloaded `SQLSRV40` from Microsoft [website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098). When I try to install it is asking for

When I install, I have to enter a path to extract files and as it mentions in the website under installation instructions No.3 "When prompted, enter the path to the PHP extensions directory".

I have `xampp` and there is a `php` file directory. For my extracting path should I just give 'C:/xampp/php'?

I am a bit confused because, the under the comment section in the answer, @Crontab mentioned "My guess would be wherever you find all the other php_*.dll files". This means all the `php_*.dll` files should be under `php` folder right?

Also, say, if I extract them into that folder or different folder, when I added `php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64` into my `php.ini` folder and connected via apache I could not find my `pdo_sqlsrv` dll.

This is my first time installing SQL server drive. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Check `phpinfo()` for [`extension_dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir)?

Comment: Put it in a script or try from command line with `php -i`... probably `C:/xampp/php/ext`

Comment: @ficuscr thank you, now I got the files extracted after just entering `C:/xampp` path. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @ficuscr One quick question, after it extracted the files, there was an `htm` file to read. I read it and it just explains what each drivers are good for. There's nothing else to install right? Just wanted to double check!

Comment: Depending on your setup perhaps a restart of Apache / php-fpm. Sounds like an MSI installer to install the sqlsrv extensions? Assume it added the include .ini's? Use `phpinfo()` or `php -m` can tell you what modules are available. Essentially need to "include" it with something like... `extension=php_sqlsrv_40_nts_vc_.dll`. Runtime configuration is also set though php.ini files.

Comment: @ficuscr I am running in a 64 bit and and I have the following `php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll` that i copied into the `php/ext` folder. I am not sure about MSI and .ini

Comment: Follow a tutorial. All PHP's extensions work the same way. Compare how rest of your PHP extensions are setup, copy same pattern. The `dll` is there, now make sure it is 'included'.

Comment: Sure, I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxfdbnpOqSI. He has '`pdo_sqlsrv` and I don't see in mine when i do the same. May be I have `7` instead of `7.1` i guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154377/discussion-between-i-n-n-m-and-ficuscr).

Comment: @ficuscr I started a chat if you have time, pls join, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeming like main issue was `sqlsrv` drivers available for download on Microsoft sites currently only support PHP 7.0.+, i.e. not PHP 7.1 or 7.2.

The solution is to either download newer drivers (https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases support for 7.2 but labeled as "technical preview") or to downgrade to PHP version 7.0.

Other common gotchas are:

- Failing to download the additional required [Microsoft ODBC drivers](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339).
- Confusion over x86 and x64 versions of drivers (also ts/nts "thread safe" and "non thread safe"). Will depend on your system/php install.

Also seeing that pecl offers the 'preview' versions of the drivers: https://pecl.php.net/package/pdo_sqlsrv/5.0.0/windows

There they also offer up this useful description:

> The Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server are PHP extensions that allow for the reading and writing of SQL Server data from within PHP scripts. The SQLSRV extension provides a procedural interface while the PDO_SQLSRV extension implements PDO for accessing data in all editions of SQL Server 2008 R2 and later (including Azure SQL DB). These drivers rely on the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to handle the low-level communication with SQL Server.